# sed delete lines containing exact number of a specific character

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to delete lines containing exactly *N* instances of a character. In this case, character `/`.

I'd prefer to use program `sed`.

Comment: At your request, I have included a `sed` alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use `sed`, the command would be:

```
sed -E -- '\-^([^/]*/[^/]*){3}$-d'
```

But if you're not required to use `sed`, the simplest solution uses `grep`.

Replace N in this command with your desired value of *N*:

```
egrep -vx '([^/]*/[^/]*){N}'
```

`grep` has a `-v` command line option which causes `grep` to display all lines which do **not** match the regular expression.  So the task then becomes to create a regular expression which matches lines that contain exactly N occurrences of the slash character, and then use `grep -v` with that regexp.

One instance is the pattern:

```
[^/]*/[^/]*
```

N instances is the pattern:

```
([^/]*/[^/]*){N}
```

Exactly N instances is the pattern:

```
^([^/]*/[^/]*){N}$
```

For patterns intended to match only entire lines, as this one is, `grep` also has the `-x` command line option.

So, let N be 3.  Does our regexp reliably match only the lines with 3 instances of `/`?

```
$ cat << EOF | egrep -x '([^/]*/[^/]*){3}'
/
//
///
////
/stuff
/stuff/added
/stuff/added/
/stuff/added/to/
/stuff/added/to/each
/stuff/added/to/each/line
more/stuff
more/stuff/added
more/stuff/added/
more/stuff/added/to/
more/stuff/added/to/each
more/stuff/added/to/each/line
consecutive//slashes/
/consecutive//slashes/
/consecutive//slashes
///all in one place
all in one place///
all in ///one place
EOF
///
/stuff/added/
more/stuff/added/
consecutive//slashes/
/consecutive//slashes
///all in one place
all in one place///
all in ///one place
```

Yes, it does appear that our regexp is matching the correct lines.  Now we simply add the `-v` flag to **filter out** the matching lines and display the lines that don't match.

```
$ cat << EOF | egrep -vx '([^/]*/[^/]*){3}'
/
//
///
////
/stuff
/stuff/added
/stuff/added/
/stuff/added/to/
/stuff/added/to/each
/stuff/added/to/each/line
more/stuff
more/stuff/added
more/stuff/added/
more/stuff/added/to/
more/stuff/added/to/each
more/stuff/added/to/each/line
consecutive//slashes/
/consecutive//slashes/
/consecutive//slashes
///all in one place
all in one place///
all in ///one place
EOF
/
//
////
/stuff
/stuff/added
/stuff/added/to/
/stuff/added/to/each
/stuff/added/to/each/line
more/stuff
more/stuff/added
more/stuff/added/to/
more/stuff/added/to/each
more/stuff/added/to/each/line
/consecutive//slashes/
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use awk: specify `/` as the field separator, and look for `n+1` fields.

```
awk -F'/' -v n=3 'NF != n + 1' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You may approach this pbm. as follows:

```
$ perl -ne 'tr|/|/| == 3 || print' inp
```

Here we rely on the property of Perl's `tr` function to return the number of translations it did on the input string, in this case, the current record. So when there are exactly three slashes in an input record, we don't print that record but in all other cases we do.

Another method this time using `POSIX sed` can be:

```
$ sed -e 's:/:/:4;t' -e 's//\n/3' -e '/\n/d' inp
```

Here we are first testing if there are more than 3 slashes, and if yes we branch to the end of sed code with the pattern space.
OTW, 3 or less slashes will be present in the pattern space. Now we test whether the third slash can be replaced by a newline, `\n`, in the pattern space. If after this substitution we see a newline => there were exactly three slashes in the input. Since we don't want to see exactly 3 slashes we delete this pattern space. OTW, whatever is left (=> a pattern space with 2 or lesser slashes) is taken to stdout.

Note: `\n` could not be found in this last case since the `s//\n/3` substitution was unsuccessful.

Yet another method using `POSIX sed` is:

```
$ sed -e h -e 's|[^/]||g' -e '/^.\{3\}$/d' -e g inp
```

Store a copy of the current record and delete all the non slashes. Now check whether there are are exactly three characters (actually now they are slashes all) in the pattern space. If yes, we promptly go ahead and delete it. OTW, recall the stored record from the hold and then sed prints it by default for you.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this might be:

- attempt to replace (substitute) the *(N+1)*<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the character; if the substitution succeeds, begin a new cycle (branch out)
- attempt to replace (substitute) the *N*<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the character; if the substitution fails, begin a new cycle (branch out)

(else)

- delete the line

Using GNU sed, and taking *N = 2*:

```
$ printf 'foo/\nfoo/bar/\nfoo/bar/baz/\n' | sed -e 's,/,/,3;t' -e 's,/,/,2;T' -ed
foo/
foo/bar/baz/
```